# Vector space of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $E=\{A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}): A^T = A\}$ and $F = \{A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}): A^T = -A\}$. How can you prove that $E$ and $F$ are vector subspaces of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?. Besides, what would its dimension even be, for $E$, $F$ and $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$? Maybe $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is direct sum of $E$ and $F$. I'm really stuck with this questions. How can matrices form a vector space? And, provided that, how can you actually compute the dimension of all those three?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be thinking of the elementary definition of vector space as being a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, or some subspace of it. There is a more general definition you should read about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Since you are given that $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space, all you have to do to show that $E$ or $F$ is a *sub*space is to verify the closure axioms: closed under addition and closed under scaling.

Closed under addition: Suppose $B$ and $C$ are elements of $E$. Now can you show that $B+C$ is an element of $E$? Something is in $E$ if and only if it equals its own transpose. To see if $B+C$ is in $E$, you should take its transpose and see if you get the original thing, i.e., verify the equation $(B+C)^T=B+C$. In order to do this, you will need the fact that $B$ and $C$ were taken from $E$, i.e., that $B^T=B$ and $C^T=C$.

Closed under scaling: Suppose $B$ is an elements of $E$ and that $\lambda$ is a scalar. Now can you show that $\lambda B$ is an element of $E$? Play the same game ...